# epoch vs. iteration in recurrent neural networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am looking at the [text generation example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py) of Keras using RNN and LSTM but still confused about the difference between the terms *epoch* and *iteration*.

Even though, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4752626/4802797) is a previous question asking the same thing, I cannot understand the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31842945/4802797), or this answer is different from how I understand it and also different from how the following example handles it. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31842945/4802797), it is said that

> one **epoch** = one forward pass and one backward pass of all the training examples
>
> number of **iterations** = number of passes, each pass using [batch size] number of examples.
>
> Example: if you have 1000 training examples, and your batch size is 500, then it will take 2 iterations to complete 1 epoch.

Conclude this: `(#training examples/batch size) = (#iterations/#epochs)`.

**However**, the following [example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py), as I understand, is different from the previous conclusion.

```
# train the model, output generated text after each iteration
for iteration in range(1, 60):
    print()
    print('-' * 50)
    print('Iteration', iteration)
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=1)

    start_index = random.randint(0, len(text) - maxlen - 1)

    for diversity in [0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.2]:
        print()
        print('----- diversity:', diversity)

        generated = ''
        sentence = text[start_index: start_index + maxlen]
        generated += sentence
        print('----- Generating with seed: "' + sentence + '"')
        sys.stdout.write(generated)

        for i in range(400):
            x = np.zeros((1, maxlen, len(chars)))
            for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
                x[0, t, char_indices[char]] = 1.

            preds = model.predict(x, verbose=0)[0]
            next_index = sample(preds, diversity)
            next_char = indices_char[next_index]

            generated += next_char
            sentence = sentence[1:] + next_char

            sys.stdout.write(next_char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        print()
```

Here, the *iteration* is **60** and number of *epoch* is set to **1**, which confused me a lot. It seems like, there are 60 *iterations*, as stated `for iteration in range(1, 60)`. And for each of the *iteration*, one *epoch* was done as stated `model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=1)` for each for-loop. And again, here, there is a `batch_size=128`. So what does the *iteration* exactly mean?

Anyone can explain the difference between *iteration* and *epoch* **based on this example**?

Comment: The term Epoch in RNN is different from the Multi layer perceptron or CNN , here epoch in the training of RNN involves single string of temporally consecutive input-output response pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in this example the **iteration** means something different : you are iterating through the learning process and after every epoch you are doing something with partially learnt model. You are doing it iteratievly and that's why an **iteration** word is used.

Comment: The term Epoch in RNN is different from the Multi layer perceptron or CNN , here epoch in the training of RNN involves single string of temporally consecutive  input-output response pairs.

Answer (score 1):

In this case iteration using just for displaing intermediate result.
We can delete this code:

```
for diversity in [0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.2]:
    print()
    print('----- diversity:', diversity)

    generated = ''
    sentence = text[start_index: start_index + maxlen]
    generated += sentence
    print('----- Generating with seed: "' + sentence + '"')
    sys.stdout.write(generated)

    for i in range(400):
        x = np.zeros((1, maxlen, len(chars)))
        for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
            x[0, t, char_indices[char]] = 1.

        preds = model.predict(x, verbose=0)[0]
        next_index = sample(preds, diversity)
        next_char = indices_char[next_index]

        generated += next_char
        sentence = sentence[1:] + next_char

        sys.stdout.write(next_char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
    print()
```

and instead:

```
for iteration in range(1, 60):
  model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=1)
```

write:

```
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=60)
```