# Iterations in DL4J?

Tags: deeplearning4j, dl4j, conv-neural-network

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752626/epoch-vs-iteration-when-training-neural-networks) and other sources **TotalIteration** = **TotalExamples**/**Batchsize** * **Epochs**. I have a CNN with 54 layers in total for 36000 examples, Batchsize of 12 and 3 Epochs. From the formula my Iteration is supposed to be `9000` but from the training-ui I am getting `3x9000 = 27000` at the end.
Tried a smaller dataset with the formula again lo and behold it's 3 times whatever the calculation was for the total iteration.

> Don't understand where the 3 is coming from or is it because my images have 3 channels(RGB) so it's seeing each channel as an example(*wonder why if this is the case, since CNNs are supposed to consume data in volumes*)

Comment: How exactly are you running your training? Can you share your training code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add: the network has two output layers and then data is fed via a multi-dataset-iterator with 3 readers added; I see where the 3 is coming from now, also realised I have 3 training folders(36000 items each) for the multi-dataset-iterator but would that not mean during training that the iterator is feeding data 1 example at a time in a batch as per 12x1 instead of 12x3 from the 3 folders for a complete pass(the 1st folder contains images, the 2nd and 3rd folders contain different corresponding image data)

Comment: or Does this mean that the network doesn't see a single multi-dataset from the iterator as 1 example but 3?